# Can this value really ever be null, or is the C# compiler just confused by code?

Tags: c#-8.0, nullable-reference-types

I've found some code that runs afoul of the new nullable reference types in C# 8, saying i could be referencing a `null`, when i cannot figure out how it could possibly ever be null:

https://dotnetfiddle.net/AoEMzp

```
public static DateTime JoinNullableDateTime(DateTime? date, DateTime? time)
{
   if ((date == null) && (time == null))
      return DateTime.MinValue;
   else if ((date != null) && (time == null))
      return date.Value.Date;
   else if ((date == null) && (time != null))
      return DateTime.MinValue.Add(time.Value.TimeOfDay);
   else
      return date.Value.Date.Add(time.Value.TimeOfDay);
}
```

Both Visual Studio and .NET Fiddle return the warnings for the last line:

> `return date.Value.Date.Add(time.Value.TimeOfDay);`

### .NET Fiddle

[image]

### Visual Studio

[image]

So my question is, can anyone give any examples of values for `date` and `time` that would cause a **NullReferenceException** in this code?

At the start, the possible combinations of null-ness are:

| date | time | Possible? |
| --- | --- | --- |
| null | null | Yes |
| not-null | null | Yes |
| null | not-null | Yes |
| not-null | not-null | Yes |

```
if ((date == null) && (time == null))`
   return DateTime.MinValue;
```

At this point the possible combinations of null-ness are:

| date | time | Possible? |
| --- | --- | --- |
| null | null | No *(because we returned)* |
| not-null | null | Yes |
| null | not-null | Yes |
| not-null | not-null | Yes |

```
else if ((date != null) && (time == null))
   return date.Value.Date;
```

At this point the possible combinations of null-ness are:

| date | time | Possible? |
| --- | --- | --- |
| null | null | No *(because we returned)* |
| not-null | null | No *(because we returned)* |
| null | not-null | Yes |
| not-null | not-null | Yes |

```
else if ((date == null) && (time != null))
   return DateTime.MinValue.Add(time.Value.TimeOfDay);
```

Finally the possible combinations of null-ness are:

| date | time | Possible? |
| --- | --- | --- |
| null | null | No *(because we returned)* |
| not-null | null | No *(because we returned)* |
| null | not-null | No *(because we returned)* |
| not-null | not-null | Yes |

So at this point it is **not possible** for date nor time to be null. Both are **guaranteed** to be `NOT NULL`.

```
else
   return date.Value.Date.Add(time.Value.TimeOfDay);
```

I cannot see any way in which either `date` or `time` could be `null` on the final line - yet there it is:

> CS8629    Nullable value type may be null.

So what am i missing?

### In fact the nulls go away even faster

After the first line

> *(date == null) && (time == null)*

We know that it is still possible for **one** of them to be null - **but not both**. So then we hit the 2nd check:

> *(date != null) && (time == null)*

Before this line we knew that only **one** was null. And now we've found the one that it was: it was `time`.

This means by the 3rd line it is **impossible** for `date` to be `null`. And yet i added a check anyway, because the compiler told me to, and the compiler is infallible. But i have the check anyway:

> *(date == null) && (time != null)*

So the extra checking even on the third `if` was redundant. And certainly it is redundant on the 4th `if`. And yet there is the compiler.

What am i doing wrong?

I'm certain i could [re-write the function](https://dotnetfiddle.net/rdrc7f) into something harder to understand, so it doesn't confuse Roslyn. But this isn't about this function, it's about the *pattern* being used - and if this pattern has lurking **NullReferenceExceptions**: *i want to know about it!*

### Bonus

I cross-checked with .NET Fiddle in case it's an artifact in my Visual Studio.

Comment: I know you are not interested in rewriting the function ... but anyway: `(date ?? DateTime.MinValue).Add(time?.TimeOfDay ?? TimeSpan.Zero)`. To me this is easier to understand and to Roslyn as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably the code analyzer is not sufficiently intelligent to conclude your `date` and `time` can never be null.

You can inform it of that fact by using the ['null forgiving' operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/null-forgiving):

```
public static DateTime JoinNullableDateTime(DateTime? date, DateTime? time)
{
   ...
   else
      return date!.Value.Date.Add(time!.Value.TimeOfDay);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Update your Visual studio to 2022.

2022 doesn't show any warning for nullable.

Download from [this](https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/vs/) link

Comment: This is wrong!  In a 'nullable' context Visual Studio 2022 **will** emit the CS8629 warning !

Comment: Why I test it in visual studio 2022 doesn't show warning?

Comment: Do you have nullable types on? Try adding `#nullable enable` at the top of your code file.